# separate similar type of substrings from a string

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I have a string that resembles an XML format.

the above string contains several substrings starting with `<SingleProvisioningRequest>` and ending with `</SingleProvisioningRequest>`.

is there a way in python such that I can put these substrings into a list.

```
"<SingleProvisioningRequest><msisdn>919949566686</msisdn>
<serviceId>104900900</serviceId>
<renewalCount>-1</renewalCount>
<isAdvanceRenewal>1</isAdvanceRenewal>
<userName>ad</userName>
<password>ad</password>
<vendorId>1</vendorId>
<circleId>AP</circleId>
<productId>4305</productId>
</SingleProvisioningRequest><SingleProvisioningRequest>
<msisdn>918698291214</msisdn>
<serviceId>20900302900</serviceId>
<renewalCount>-1</renewalCount>
<isAdvanceRenewal>1</isAdvanceRenewal>
<userName>ad</userName>
<vendorId>1</vendorId>
<circleId>MAH</circleId>
<productId>7956</productId>
</SingleProvisioningRequest>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex `(?<=<SingleProvisioningRequest>)[\s\S]+?(?=<\/SingleProvisioningRequest>)`

See it working here, it matches whatever is between the tags you described [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sAir93/1)

Note it uses a lookbehind for the beginning tag and a lookahead for the finishing one. The part at the middle is a non greedy trick for matching everything between.

As for python this should work to place the matches in a list:

```
p = re.compile('(?<=<SingleProvisioningRequest>)[\s\S]+?(?=<\/SingleProvisioningRequest>)')

p.findall('YOUR TEXT HERE')
```

Update for your update (matching the tags too): [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sAir93/2)

```
<SingleProvisioningRequest>[\s\S]+?<\/SingleProvisioningRequest>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as correct so answer can help other people, and welcome to SO :)

Comment: your method does not inlcude <SingleProvisioningRequest> and <\SingleProvisioningRequest> in list of strings returned ...i want to inlude these tags also in the strings

Comment: @MehtabAnjum I though you didn't want the tags, I've a included a new version that includes the tag in the answer. Cheers.